# artemiss mission and artemis program tags, do we need both? If so, how to know which one to use?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are tags for [artemis-mission](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artemis-mission) (13) and [artemis-program](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artemis-program) (8) and currently on both tags the message reads:

> There is no usage guidance for this tag … yet!

I chose one for [Demonstrative examples of NASA "programs that go too long, that cost too much... end up getting cast out later"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46704/12102) at random because I don't know the difference.

Do we need both? If so how should we use each one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple Artemis missions in the Artemis program. It looks like, if anything, we should have [artemis-1](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artemis-1), [artemis-2](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artemis-2), etc. Probably, best to just merge [artemis-mission](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artemis-mission) into [artemis-program](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artemis-program) though, since it looks like it's been used for more than one mission.

Comment: Yep, I agree that's best for now.

Comment: @uhoh Merge and synonym complete!